# Is the attribute align legal to use in HTML5?

Tags: html, attributes, alignment

Recently, I'm editing a website which is coded by previous worker. And I saw this

```
<div align="right"><table>...</table></div>
```

And this table is well aligned to the right. But I didn't see this `align` attribute on w3school. (It seems to be copied from Excel or Word.)

Is this attribute `align` legal to use in HTML5?

Comment: there is only align-self or align-items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No in HTML5 `align` attribute is deprecated. Though, you can use style sheet `text-align` property.

In case of deprecated `valign` attribute, you can use `vertical-align` property.

Also, if you going to make flex box, use `align-content` property to align contents.

Comment: It isn’t deprecated in HTML 5. If it was, it would still be legal.

Comment: @Quentin check out this list of HTML5 deprecated tags and attributes on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm)

Comment: Check out the specification instead of a third-party resource that uses the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2):

`align` on `div` elements is listed in the HTML specification under [Non-conforming features](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) which says:

> Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors

It was deprecated (in favour of CSS) in 1998 when HTML 4 came out.